# Ionic 3 Project does not have config.xml

Tags: xml, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I was trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOjamH1bAA. 
But I couldn't even begin, because from what it looks like, my project does not have a config.xml file and I tried looking up the documentation online, and it says nothing about it, I also tried searching how to generate it, didn't find anything, why am I missing this config.xml? how to generate this file? Here's a link to display where its supposed to be, and it's not there:

[image]

heres the ionic info output:

```
Ionic: ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.1.1 (C:\Users\Publio\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic) Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2 @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11 System: NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe) npm : 6.3.0 OS : Windows 10
```

Comment: when you did `ionic start app <type>`.. what did you select for cordova option?

Comment: Also can you add the output of `ionic info` to the question?

Comment: nothing at first, but it kept asking me if i wanted to install it, and back then i didn't need it, now i tried doing npm install -g cordova and nothing happened, also i recently updated my ionic version, and the messages suggesting me to install cordova were gone

Comment: can you [edit] it in the question?

Comment: also `npm -g cordova` just installs the global cordova cli and not the integration to your app

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From ionic cli v4, you need to set cordova to your ionic app if you are creating an ionic cordova application. `config.xml` is used by cordova platform.

You can enable the integration after creating the app as well according to [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/integrations-enable).

```
ionic integrations enable cordova
```

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot recover or don't have a config.xml file [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-load-empty-config-xml-file-android-build/119461/7) is a solution I found from,
just run `ionic integrations enable cordova --add` and if it asks to overwrite **config.xml**, give **yes** and if it asks to overwrite **resources**, give **no** because it will overwrite your resources folder and you will lose many important things

Answer (score 0):

run cmd

**ionic integrations enable cordova --add**

update config.xml file and package.json file

Answer (score -2):

create new project and copy config.xml file and create a new file with name config.xml and paste in it