# In ionic 4, i got cordova not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

i have tried lot of things still cordova not installed.
[image]

What to do Next?

Comment: ... are you in an ionic cordova project? did you install Cordova CLI? doesnt look like it

Comment: You have to install cordova globally with ` npm install -g cordova ` command and then you can check cordova version with ` cordova --version  ` command .Good Luck !!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52003359/4826457

Comment: I tried npm install -g cordova... still not solved

Comment: Try  `ionic doctor fix` !

Comment: npm install -g cordova     gives error  -  'cordova' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file....

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 4 introduced two method.one is cordova plugin another one is capacitor.ionic 4 not installing default plugin in cordova

if you  want cordova plungin.create ionic      project.Using following commands

ionic cordova build andriod
ionic cordova build ios